# Algebraic manipulation question find inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

Could someone explain which algebraic manipulations is used to get the result on the right side of the red box.

In my opinion will $$ \frac {2}{x-2}={y-1}$$ lead to

$$ \frac {2}{y-1}+2={x}$$

So how do i get $$ \frac {1}{2
({y-2})}+2={x}$$
??

[question in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbxvq.png)

Comment: You're right: it should be $\dfrac{2}{y-1}+2=x$

Comment: provided neither $x = 2,$, nor $y=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We get by multiplication by $$(x-2)$$:$$2=(x-2)(y-1)$$ and then dividing by $$y-1$$
so we get
$$\frac{2}{y-1}=x-2$$
adding $$2$$ so we get
$$\frac{2}{y-1}+2=x$$

Comment: provided neither $x = 2,$, nor $y=1$.  One must check separately in each case.  The given equation is undefined at $x=2$, or when $y=1$, or both.